# How do I use OutputDebugString with a std::string?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do:

```
std::string line = "bla";
OutputDebugString( line.c_str() );
```

It won't compile, says it can't convert `const char*` to `LPCWSTR`. Is there no way to output `std::string` to the debug window?

I also don't understand why this appears to work in this tutorial video here: https://youtu.be/EIzkeFTpMq0?list=PLqCJpWy5Fohfil0gvjzgdV4h29R9kDKtZ&t=2101

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your project is configured to compile for Unicode, so `OutputDebugString()` maps to `OutputDebugStringW()`, which expects a `const wchar_t*` as input, not a `const char*`, hence the error.

The code in the video works because the presenter's project is configured to compile for ANSI, so `OutputDebugString()` maps to `OutputDebugStringA()` instead.

So, you need to either:

- use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`:

  ```
  std::wstring line = L"bla";
  OutputDebugString( line.c_str() );
  ```
- use `OutputDebugStringA()` instead of `OutputDebugString()`:

  ```
  std::string line = "bla";
  OutputDebugStringA( line.c_str() );
  ```